# Angular Build Fails After Adding Three.js

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js, angular8

I've created a fresh Angular app and added `three` and `@types/three` and created a basic component.
But when I run `ng build --prod`, I get those errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/three/src/core/BufferAttribute.d.ts:21:6 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

21  set needsUpdate( value: boolean );
        ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUtils.d.ts:3:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGL2RenderingContext'.

3  constructor( gl: WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext, extensions: any, capabilities: any );
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/three/src/core/InterleavedBufferAttribute.d.ts:20:6 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

20  get count(): number;
        ~~~~~
node_modules/three/src/core/InterleavedBufferAttribute.d.ts:21:6 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

21  get array(): ArrayLike<number>;
        ~~~~~
node_modules/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLAttributes.d.ts:6:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGL2RenderingContext'.

6  constructor( gl: WebGLRenderingContext | WebGL2RenderingContext );
```

Adding `three` to the Typescript types array did not help:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["three"]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`three.js` depends on TypeScript `3.7`. Starting with `@angular/cli@9.0.0-rc.10` and `@angular/core@9.0.0-rc.9` you should be able to use TypeScript 3.7 with Angular, too. More details about this at the Angular repository:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16071#issuecomment-577109414

`three.js R112`